# Async Action creator test cases using jest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to `writing the test cases` in react. Here, I have an action creator which is like ,

```
export function fetchUserJd() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    let url = FETCH_JD_ROOT_URL + page + "&" + size;
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_INITIATED
    })
    get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response data",response.payload)
        if (response.status === 200) {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED,
          });
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS,
            data: response.payload,
          }
          )
        }
        else {
          dispatch({
            type: REQUEST_SUCCESSED
          })
          toastr.error("Error while fetching Job Description, Please check again");
          if (response.status === "") {
            toastr.error('Our server is down. Please check again');
          }
          dispatch({
            type: FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_FAILED,
            data: response.status,
          });
          if (response.status === 401) {
            toastr.error('Please Login Again');
            localStorage.clear();
            history.push('/');
          }
        }
      })
  }
};
```

So, Here I am trying to write the test case for this.

So, what I have tried is ,

```
beforeEach(function () {
    moxios.install();
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('creates GET_POSTS_SUCCESS after successfuly fetching postse', () => {
    moxios.wait(() => {
      const request = moxios.requests.mostRecent();
      console.log("request is",request);
      request.respondWith({
        status: 200,
        response: dataResponse,
      });
    });

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: 'FETCHING_JOBDESCRIPTION_SUCCESS', data: dataResponse },
    ];

    const store = mockStore({ data: {} })

    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchUserJd()).then(() => {
      // return of async actions
      expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });
  });
```

Now, I am getting this error which is like,

```
● Header component actions › creates GET_POSTS_SUCCESS after successfuly fetching postse

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

      at Object.it (src/modules/header/actions/_tests_/index.test.js:64:53)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Now,Here I actually not understanding why this error is getting appeared.

As I am calling an action and then I am checking that ,as it is calling the expected or not.

```
export const get = (url) =>
    axios.get(
        url,
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("access_token") !== null ? `Bearer ` + localStorage.getItem("access_token") : null,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
    ).then(data => {
        if (data.status === HttpStatus.OK) {
            return {
                status: data.status,
                payload: data.data
            };
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        return {
            status: err.response.data,
            payload: null
        };
    });
```

So, Can any one help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your error comes from here but it's not the problem.

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchUserJd()).then(() => {
  // return of async actions
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
});
```

This part of your code tries to use the 'then' function of dispatch(which doesn't return a Promise at the moment). It is not something that returns a Promise. The initial call to actions.fetchUserJd() doesn't have any asynchronous behavior, it returns a function that has access to dispatch, and that function makes an API call(asynchronous) but handles the ***.then()*** internally and doesn't return it.

*This means that to be able to wait for it to be done. You could make the return of your action a Promise, like in the example for [mocking async actions](https://github.com/dmitry-zaets/redux-mock-store#asynchronous-actions)*.

His example is below

```
function fetchData () {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch('/users.json') // Here returning the .then() of the fetch(equivalent of your get) is returning a promise, that's why for him the .then() call on the dispatch works in his tests !
      .then(() => dispatch(success()))
  };
}
```

Then you could use your original code.

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchUserJd()).then(() => {
  // return of async actions
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
});
```

Completely unrelated thing to note is that you don't directly use the rejected handler function of the get call in your action.
ex:

```
get('http://localhost:3000/example')
   .then(
   (successData) => {
       // Do whatever you want to in case of positive resolution of the get call...
       // Will contain your response code and your data.
    },
    (rejectData) => {
       // Do whatever you want if the request fails, its error data is caught inside rejectData
    }
)
```

Comment: I did that using the return before the the get call

Comment: return get(url)
      .then((response) => {

Comment: I have updated the code there I am adding the get(url) function code

Comment: That function returns a promise, yes. but you ignore that in your call to it. You just call it, without chaining the return values.

ex:

    `function addNumbers(num1, num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }`

    and later it's called:  `addnumbers(4, 2);`

    you need to do `return addNumbers(4, 2);`

    at no moment am I using the return of the function!

Comment: @ganeshkaspate So? What was the problem finally?